# How to get internet back in virtual machine if host loses connection

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM and if my host loses internet connection or I disable it and re-enable it the host will have internet normally, but the VM loses connection and I can't get it back unless if I reboot that VM.

Is there a way to get the internet back in VM without rebooting it?

Comment: try to restart networking service using this command : /etc/init.d/networking restart (if you're not logged as root user :
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart  )

Comment: it just hangs...says `[.....]Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service` and it's like freezed

Comment: OK i did it now with sudo and it restarted....but still no internet connection. `ping google.com ping: unknown host google.com`

Comment: virtualbox vm's have lots of issues with networking. Then if restarting networking service doesn't work i don't think you can do something else

Comment: Yes that would be good, you even get an achievement if you chose it as right answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is very familiar as it seems and I have experimented a little and it turns out that you can change the network adapter while the VM is running here:

[image]

and then change only the `Attached to:` option to NAT or Bridged Adapter (mine was on Bridged adapter so i changed it to NAT).

[image]
[image]

and click OK. And then change it again to which it was before and again click on OK to accept it.

Now go back to your VM terminal and run this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

UPDATE for Ubuntu 18+ or other similar versions which use netplan

```
sudo netplan apply
```

And your internet should work now.

Comment: If anyone can explain WHY this works that would be great

Comment: It seems being related to the network on the host machine.
If you switch the network-adapter I suppose the one of the host-machine is re-instantiated too.
So in general you need a script to instantiate both new with one function or button.
It's possible that you can switch the adapter between host-system and virtual client-system on "always listening", then the script would be deplorable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanx David....i think this should be interesting for Oracle...maybe they can implement this somehow :)

Comment: Have a look on the network adapters on your host-system.
There perhaps you can adjust the required "listening".

Comment: just to add, it worked but after trying 2-3 times. may be network interface restarting could be a bit slow process.